# Add a new class to the icheck-helper class with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, icheck

Using the *iCheck* plugin in JQuery, I am trying to add a new CSS class to the `iCheck-helper` element. I tried as follows:

```
$('.iCheck-helper').addClass('abc');
```

However it doesn't work.

Comment: Your query works perfectly, are you sure you have the JQuery library included? And that there exists an element with the class `iCheck-helper` (Make sure you don't have incorrect casing)

Comment: i've added jquery library already.

Comment: You did not mention in your question that you were using a plugin, what plugin is `iCheck-helper` from? Could you also add the HTML element that has the class `iCheck-helper`

Comment: Sorry for the sketchy question. This iCheck-helper class belongs to the self-created iCheck plugin

Comment: Improved title and body. Added relevant tags.

Comment: Are you sure the `DOM` element exists when this code is running?

Comment: I found a way to add a new class to the iCheck-helper class using the setTimeOut function in jquery. Thanks for all the contributions from everyone

Answer (score 0):

Here is how is can be done in `vanilla` javascript.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.querySelector('.classOne').classList.add('classTwo');
```

```css
.classOne {
  color: blue;
}

.classTwo {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="classOne">Test</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it doesn't work because the iCheck-helper class is Plugin